# WP8 Listbox jumpy when loading more elements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have been implementing infinite scroll in my app, but when the `List` loads more elements the `ScrollView` Scroll position is not in the same place than before.

The auto scroll (which works well):

```
private void VideosList_ItemRealized(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer sv = VideosList.Descendents().OfType<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (sv != null && this.isloading == false && sv.VerticalOffset >= (sv.ScrollableHeight - 60))
        {
            this.isloading = true;
            videosList.getMoreVideos(20);
        }
        //videosList.getMoreVideos(5);
    }
```

The binding

```
public void videosListUpdateFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YTVideoPage.Focus();
    VideosList.ItemsSource = null;
    VideosList.ItemsSource = videosList.ytvideos.data.items;
    this.isloading = false;
}
```

How I can get the listbox to remain in the same position when changing the binding? I've tried to get `VerticalOffset` and set it when load but it doesn't work.

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: For reference, now i'm using an ObservableCollection, so i deleted the line "VideosList.ItemsSource = null;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the new LongListSelector for WP8? This one works quite well for infinite scrolling. There are also examples how to use this like: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e

Unfortunately, the twitter API has changed and you won't receive any data, but the example code still helped me to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you, now i'm using LongListSelector and it Works! I'm not trying to use Twitter data. For future reference is bad idea using a ListBox to implement infinite scroll, VerticalOffset changes every time to an unexpected value, i don't know why.